# Marking duplicates in a separate column using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Suppose I have the following pandas data frame, df1, in a jupyter notebook from an excel file:

```
Name    ID      Password
A       User_1  PW_1
A       User_2  PW_2
A       User_3  PW_3
B       User_4  PW_4
B       User_5  PW_5
C       User_6  PW_6
```

I'd like to add a new column, called `STAT`, that goes through the `Name` column, and for every item in `Name`, if the previous cell in `Name` contained the same item, print `dup` (for duplicate) in `STAT`; otherwise, don't put anything. In my example above, Users 2,3, and 5 should have `dup` in the `SRC` column after my operation.

Here is my attempt. I add a new blank column called `STAT` using `df1.insert`, and then I run:

```
for index, name in enumerate(df1['Name']):
    if index > 0:
        if df1['Name'][index - 1] == name:
            df1.ix[index, 'STAT'] = 'dup'`
```

This works fine, but I'd like to know

a) if it can be improved

and more importantly

b) Why it's throwing a `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame` warning despite my using .ix. Even .loc throws the warning.

It would be easy to check ordinarily, but I'm using jupyter notebook in PyCharm, and every time I reload the file I get a `_xrsf argument missing from POST.`

Relevant snippet of code, applied to my actual example. df names will differ:

```
sort_full = full_set.sort_values(['Name','SRC'])
dupless_full = sort_full.drop_duplicates(subset = ['Name', 'ER', 'ID', 
'PW'], keep = 'last')
dupless_full.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)

dupless_full['STAT'] = np.where(dupless_full['Name'] == 
dupless_full['Name'].shift(), 'dup', "")
```

Comment: Are values in `Name` column sorted?

Comment: Yes. In fact, they are sorted by another column, called SRC, taking values A or B, after they have been sorted by name. I chose to not include that information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use np.where

```
df1['Stat'] = np.where(df['Name'] == df['Name'].shift(), 'Dupe', np.nan)

    Name    ID      Password    Stat
0   A       User_1  PW_1        nan
1   A       User_2  PW_2        Dupe
2   B       User_3  PW_3        nan
3   C       User_4  PW_4        nan
```

Comment: Well, again, this works, and is faster than my solution, but it still throws the same warning.

Comment: How did you generate the dataframe? If its not generated using .copy(), it would lead to copy warning.

Comment: I'm not using .copy(), because I was told that was never the correct way to generate a data frame. Is that nonsense?

Comment: Can you post the code that you are using to create the dataframe?

Comment: Tacked it on to the end.

Comment: That part of the code looks fine. The settingwithcopywarning occurs when you try to modify a dataframe that was created without .loc or .copy(), effectively creating a view of the original dataframe rather than a copy. You may want to look at how the sort_full was created

Comment: I never used .copy or .loc, which is why I'm confused. I ended up calling my dataframe using .copy, and it went away, but I don't think that's very memory efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If values in column `Name` are sorted is possible use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) for boolean mask:

```
df1['Stat'] = np.where(df1['Name'].duplicated(), 'Dupe', '')
print (df1)
  Name      ID Password  Stat
0    A  User_1     PW_1      
1    A  User_2     PW_2  Dupe
2    B  User_3     PW_3      
3    C  User_4     PW_4
```

If values are not sorted, I add comparison with another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46271854/2901002):

```
df1['Stat_shift'] = np.where(df1['Name'] == df1['Name'].shift(), 'Dupe', np.nan)
df1['Stat_duplicated'] = np.where(df1['Name'].duplicated(), 'Dupe', '')
print (df1)
  Name      ID Password Stat_shift Stat_duplicated
0    A  User_1     PW_1        nan                
1    A  User_2     PW_2       Dupe            Dupe
2    B  User_3     PW_3        nan                
3    A  User_2     PW_2        nan            Dupe
4    C  User_4     PW_4        nan                
5    B  User_3     PW_3        nan            Dupe
6    B  User_3     PW_3       Dupe            Dupe
```

Comment: I think, OP wants to check only previous value, not all duplicates in frame.

Comment: It is possible, but if values are sorted this should workling too.

Comment: I meant, only if values are sorted, this'll work, but I'm not sure if OP stated that anywhere.

Comment: Yes, exactly. So I add this to answer.

Comment: I want to list all duplicates as 'dup' except the first one. Let me edit my example, to clarify.

Comment: As with the solution above, this throws me the same warning I mentioned in the OP. It works, and it's fast, though.